# Transferring Video files to iPhone

Tags: iphone, file-transfer

How could I transfer / copy Video files directly from my Laptop to my iPhone3GS?

Comment: Do you mean without iTunes?

Comment: And on what os? Mac, win or linux?

Comment: Does this also include converting them to an iPhone compatible format?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use iTunes then it is not possible. There is software that can manage your file collection on your iPhone but any of the half decent applications require that iTunes be installed anyway. At that point you may as well use iTunes.

If your talking about transferring videos with converting them, the answer is definitely no. The iPhone only supports very specific formats. You can easily find free software such as [WinX Free iPhone Converter](http://www.winxdvd.com/free-iphone-converter/) that will convert almost any format.

Lastly, all of the above is assuming you are using Windows. While the Mac is on par for iTunesless iPhone syncing the only solution I have been able to find for syncing a 3GS in linux is to install Windows XP under a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Sign up for and download [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com), and download the free iPhone app as well. Then you can just drag and drop videos from your desktop and they will sync to your iPhone.